# Mount filesystem folders usign SSHFS on servers where root SSH access is disable on Linux

Tags: sshfs

I have SSH access to a server as an ordinary user. In this server SSH root access is disable.  From my laptop which runs Ubuntu 12.04, I can use "Connect to Server" option in Nautilus to see and access the folders that my user has permission on this server, and I can also see other folders that my user have no access.

When I need, for example, to edit a file that only root has permission I first login in this server using SSH with my personal credentials and then a become root and so on. 
This is fine, but if I want to use my GUI text editor which is not installed on the server I have to use scp and sync the file back ...

So my question is: after mount this remote folder in Nautilus is there any way to give this Nautilus Window a kind of root access ? What I mean is, I'd like to use Nautilus to browse in this server on the folders that only root have access, for example. 
If this is possible only by command line it is fine. As long as I can CD to such folders and be able to launch from the terminal my local applications to edit such files.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not quite the answer you want to hear, but to access a file as root you will need to log in as root.  As you already have root access on the machine, you can (not necessarily should, but can) modify ssh to allow root logins.  [ If you want to know how to do that, ask a question and I can answer it, its not hard ]

Another work-around could be to set set up x-forwarding (and xauth and your gui editor on the server) and then edit the file in the GUI on the server, with the screen forwarded to your desktop.   Its a bit tricky to set up, but not hard.  You will probably want to enable compression on your SSH connection as well if you do this though, else it can be needlessly slow on bandwidth-constrained connections)

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for your suggestions. 1 it is not suitable for this server because of security reasons. The suggestion 2 is also very good alternative and in fact I have used it sometimes, but in my case it was extremely low.